# Is it possible to run 3 monitors as a single with 2 different physical sizes?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I hope the title wasn't too confusing.  I currently use Nvidia Control Panel to run 3 46" HD TVs as a single monitor with them configured like below.

My current setup basically a U with me in the center:

[image: My current setup basically a U with me in the center]

What I want know is if there is some 3rd party software out there that would allow me to run a configuration like this?

What I'd like to have two 46" on the right and left with a 55" in center. A U with a large trough l__l:

[image: What I'd like to have two 46" on the right and left with a 55" in center. A U with a large trough l__l]

I use this setup for sim racing so while the first setup is functional you're not getting the correct sight picture like you would if really on the track in a car.

I've also got a post on my blog scheduled to drop in a few days and want to triple check that nothing new has come out that would the second option to work *-- Awesome! --* and to make me look foolish. *-- Way less awesome! --*

Answer (score 2):

THE GPU doesn't care at all how large the displays are physically, only what resolution they are. If your new 55" has a higher resolution than the existing displays, you might get something closer to what you want - 'more picture' in front of you. If it's the same resolution, then it will show the same image as before… just bigger.

Comment: Let's say they all run at 1920x1080.  Would dropping the resolution on the two side monitors to say 1440x1080 be possible when using Nvidia Surround?  I know it's possible when running them as 3 separate displays, but I think Surround may take the lowest resolution display and apply that across all 3?

Comment: Sorry, idk how Nvidia Surround works. You'd have to try it.